# using awk, how to print multiple input lines to a single csv row?

Tags: sql, bash, csv, awk

My role is changing from desktop support to application support here at work, so this is pretty new to me. As part of that process, I've been tasked with learning the basics of Linux and soon SQL. I learn with real examples best, but I'm not learning well enough yet!

We have a process I'd like to automate for a user. I could always contact the vendor to ask them to change their process, but I am trying to make the most of this learning time.

We get an HTML email that shows exceptions to an import process and the user checks a table to find out the organization's ID and then looks up the exception in another table by the org's ID. What I'd like to do is split out the info he needs to make a match into a CSV. My ultimate goal is to then make a SQL query to take the .CSV and look up from one table then the other then output the reason for the exception for him.

I'd like to stick with awk since I've spent a couple days already trying to really get it hammered down, but what do I know? I've found other posts that look like doing this in VB to make the process integrated with Outlook and Excel would be better, but when the only tool you have is a hammer...

The email input file looks like this to awk:

```
<strong>Request Made By: </strong>Joe Schmoe(<a href="mailto:joeschmoe@joemail.com">joeschmoe@joemail.com</a>)<o:p></o:p></li><li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1">
<strong>Request from: </strong>Kentucky - Highway<o:p></o:p></li><li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1">
<strong>Receiving Ministry:</strong> District Project<o:p></o:p></li><li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1">
<strong>Receiving Ministry Name:</strong> Papua New Guinea Hospital<o:p></o:p></li><li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1">
<strong>Intent of Gift</strong> Use funds toward building and renovating hospitals.<o:p></o:p></li><li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1">
<strong>Gift Type:</strong> Cash<o:p></o:p></li><li class="MsoNormal" style="mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1">
<strong>Amount:</strong> 500.00<o:p></o:p></li></ul>
```

The relevant info is the email address, receiving ministry name and amount; those should reveal a unique entry. I apparently don't understand grouping commands so I'm piping a lot. My problem is that I can't get the result from the second search (receiving ministry name) to show up on the same line as the first search (email address). My goal is this:

```
joeschmoe@joemail.com,Papua New Guinea Hospital,500.00
```

And then a new line for the next error from the same email. The dollar input may or may not have a decimal.

Here's what I have cobbled together so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '/Request Made By:/' ~/emailSort/FW* | awk -F'(' '{print $2}' | awk -F'<' '{print $1}' | awk -F'\n' 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} {print $1}' > output.csv
awk '/Receiving Ministry Name:/' ~/emailSort/FW* | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' >> output.csv
awk '/Amount:/' ~/emailSort/FW* | awk -F'(' '{print $2}' >> output.csv
```

And here's my result:

```
joeschmoe@joemail.com

Papua New Guinea Hospital
```

And a few more blanks after that.
I haven't really touched the third line yet since I'm hung up on this basic problem. The file name this time is FW_ FTM Point To Point.

If you wouldn't mind explaining the "why?" behind any code or syntax, I would appreciate it. I'm attempting this in a shell script in Ubuntu 17.04 on a vm.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** one-line approach:

```
awk -F'<[^><]+>' 'BEGIN{s=""; OFS=","}{if($2~/Request Made By:/) s=s$4; 
    else if($2~/Receiving Ministry Name:|Amount:/) s=s OFS $3} END {print s}' file
```

The output:

```
joeschmoe@joemail.com, Papua New Guinea Hospital, 500.00
```

---

`-F'<[^><]+>'` - to separate fields by tags (`<tagname>`)

Comment: @dawg there's nothing gawk-specific about that script, it will work in any awk. What part did you think was gawk-specific?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your data contains name->value mappings I find it easiest to work with them by first creating an array to hold those mappings (`n2v[]` below) and then you can just access the values by their names to do whatever you like with them:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":? *<[^<>]+> *"; OFS="," }
{
    gsub(OFS," ")
    name = $2
    value = (name == "Request Made By" ? $4 : $3)
    n2v[name] = value
}
name == "Amount" {
    print n2v["Request Made By"], n2v["Receiving Ministry Name"], n2v["Amount"]
    delete n2v
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
joeschmoe@joemail.com,Papua New Guinea Hospital,500.00
```

The following shows how this approach makes all name->value mappings available to you:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":? *<[^<>]+> *"; OFS="," }
{
    gsub(OFS," ")
    name = $2
    value = (name == "Request Made By" ? $4 : $3)
    n2v[name] = value
}
name == "Amount" {
    # print n2v["Request Made By"], n2v["Receiving Ministry Name"], n2v["Amount"]
    for (name in n2v) {
        print name, n2v[name]
    }
    delete n2v
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Request from,Kentucky - Highway
Request Made By,joeschmoe@joemail.com
Amount,500.00
Gift Type,Cash
Intent of Gift,Use funds toward building and renovating hospitals.
Receiving Ministry Name,Papua New Guinea Hospital
Receiving Ministry,District Project
```

Since your output is CSV, if you can have a comma in any of the input fields that you want output then you have to handle that by either using `gsub(OFS," ")` like I did to replace them with some other char, or adding double quotes around each field when outputting them (if whatever you're going to do next supports having separators inside quoted fields) or something else at your discretion...

Comment: Oh man of course variables! I got so caught up in the "first process this, then process that," that I forgot about that! Thank you, I tried the code on the real deal which was a forward of a forward and it worked great without getting hung up on any false positives. NOW I'm going to try to make sure I understand WHY it works. Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an awk expert, but when I want to print multiple searches on the same line I use a single awk statement and assign each collected value to a variable:

```
cat file.txt |awk '
/line 1 search/ {var1=$1} 
/line 2 search/ {var2=$1} 
/line 3 search/ {var3=$1} 
{if (var1 && var2 && var3) 
    {print var1","var2","var3
    var1=""
    var2=""
    var3=""}
 }'
```

Like that.  Notice that I re-set the variables to nothing to make sure I don't get printouts all the time, or partials.  Here's a working example:

```
# cat afile
In this file the name is Joe Schmoe
On this separate line the place is Papua New Guinea Hospital
The amount of thing is 500.00
In this file the name is Jane Lane
On this separate line the place is Virginia Mason
The amount of thing is 100.00

#cat afile |awk -F" is " '
/name/ {name=$2} 
/place/ {place=$2} 
/amount/ {amount=$2} 
{if (name && place && amount) 
    {print name","place","amount
    name=""
    place=""
    amount=""}
}'

Joe Schmoe,Papua New Guinea Hospital,500.00
Jane Lane,Virginia Mason,100.00
```

A solution for your file would be much more complicated this way, though, because it would require you to use string manipulation functions like `match()` and `substr()` to print out just what you're looking for and nothing else:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

I think if I were tasked to do this, I would probably  `awk -F"<\/strong>"` and then use `split()` by "(" for the name and "<" for the place and amount, and take the first match in the resulting array that `split()` made.